# Arranging cubes into an X-shape via For-loop statement

Tags: for-loop, maya, modeling, autodesk, mel

I've been attempting to arrange cubes in an X-shape using the following code. To better understand what the final product should resemble, imagine each cube representing a pixel.

They should be stacked in a staircase pattern, edges touching only. 200 for each direction (1 being the central cube, 199 for each block per 1 of 4 diagonal directions.) Here's what I got so far:

```
// CENTRAL BASE CUBE
polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ; 

int $i;
for ( $i = 0; $i < 199; i++ ) {

    // CUBE BRANCH TOP LEFT
    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 -3.0 -3.1 ;

    // CUBE BRANCH TOP RIGHT
    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 3.0 3.1 ;

    // CUBE BRANCH BOTTOM LEFT
    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 0.3 0.04 ;

    // CUBE BRANCH BOTTOM RIGHT
    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 -0.3 -0.04 ;
}
```

I've tried running my current script above, and it won't execute due to returning the error below. This one seems to be syntactical, despite that seemingly being correct from what I know. I think it might have something to do with the first instance of `$i` not highlighting in Maya's editor despite the second highlighting (not recognised by editor?):

```
// Error: for ($i=0; $i<199; i++)
//
// Error: Line 4.22: Invalid use of Maya object "i".
```

Comment: Excuse the weeks of silence: adjusted code to work

Used 1st for to construct the base @ 0. Each move multiplies X & Y incremented base 1:


for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
 polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0;
 move -r ($i*1) ($i*1) 0;
 }
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){
 polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0;
 move -r ($i*-1) ($i*1) 0;
 }
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){
 polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0;
 move -r ($i*1) ($i*-1) 0;
 }
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){
 polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0;
 move -r ($i*-1) ($i*-1) 0;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you've made a mistake in the code. Missing `$` in `$i++`.

Secondly, if `$i = 0` and `$i < 200` you'll get 200 cubes on every 1/4 side (not 199).

Thirdly, use `(+/-2 * $i)` for incremental move in every direction (out of 4).

Here's what a code looks like:

```
polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;

int $i ;

for ($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++) {

    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 (2*$i) (2*$i) ;

    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 (-2*$i) (-2*$i) ;

    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 (2*$i) (-2*$i) ;

    polyCube -ch on -o on -w 1.5 -h 2 -d 2 ;
    move -r 0 (-2*$i) (2*$i) ;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i<199; $i++){}
```

and read this https://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/RobTheBloke/www/mel/for_loop.html